# Battery Monitor error in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, power-management, battery

So,I tried installing battery-monitor to provide visual alerts for low battery since it happens that my system just shuts down at low battery.
I ran the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maateen/battery-monitor
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install battery-monitor
```

Now when I try to open `battery-monitor` I get the following error(I was opening through terminal)

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/battery-monitor/run.py", line 14, in <module>
    from AppIndicator import AppIndicator
  File "/usr/share/battery-monitor/AppIndicator.py", line 10, in <module>
    gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 130, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
ValueError: Namespace AppIndicator3 not available
```

So how do I rectify this error?
Suggestions for other low-battery notification methods are also accepted.
I run Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

You need to run:

```
sudo apt install gir1.2-appindicator3-{yourversion}
```